# Compound model scaffold in ASP.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following class models in ASP.net MVC 3:

```
public class Application 
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
  public BusinessBaseData Bbd { get; set; }
}

public class BusinessBaseData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public EconomicSector { get; set }
}
```

When I use Visual Studio 2010 to create a Edit view, and therefore asking for code scaffolding, I get a HTML *TextBox* for the **CreatedOn** field, but not for the BusinessBaseData **Name** and **EconomicSector** fields.

I want to automatically generate code for one-to-one relationships, and make that code available on the base class edit page. Should I use partials, or is there a cleaner way?

Thank you very much,
Bruno

**EDIT:**

@hunter, here is the code I get (I'm using Razor Engine):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    @*<legend>Fields</legend>*@

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedOn)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedOn)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreatedOn)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you show the EditorTemplate markup?